# Can't install r package "bsts" due to "had status 127"

Tags: r, install.packages

I can't install package "bsts":

```
> install.packages("bsts")
also installing the dependencies ‘BoomSpikeSlab’, ‘Boom’


There are binary versions available but the source versions are later:
               binary source needs_compilation
BoomSpikeSlab  0.5.2  0.7.0              TRUE
Boom             0.2    0.5             FALSE
bsts           0.6.2  0.6.5              TRUE

Binaries will be installed
trying URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.2/BoomSpikeSlab_0.5.2.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 2359323 bytes (2.3 MB)
downloaded 2.3 MB

trying URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.2/bsts_0.6.2.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 2612461 bytes (2.5 MB)
downloaded 2.5 MB

package ‘BoomSpikeSlab’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘bsts’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
C:\Users\R612965\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpMRjXXu\downloaded_packages
installing the source package ‘Boom’

trying URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/Boom_0.5.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 1061942 bytes (1.0 MB)
downloaded 1.0 MB

* installing *source* package 'Boom' ...
** package 'Boom' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs

*** arch - i386
Warning: running command 'make -f "Makevars" -f "C:/FAST/R/323F40~1.1/etc/i386/Makeconf" 
-f "C:/FAST/R/323F40~1.1/share/make/winshlib.mk" CXX='$(CXX1X) $(CXX1XSTD)' 
CXXFLAGS='$(CXX1XFLAGS)' CXXPICFLAGS='$(CXX1XPICFLAGS)' 
SHLIB_LDFLAGS='$(SHLIB_CXX1XLDFLAGS)' SHLIB_LD='$(SHLIB_CXX1XLD)' 
SHLIB="Boom.dll" ' had status 127
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'Boom'
* removing 'C:/FAST/R/3.2.1/library/Boom'
Warning in install.packages :
running command '"C:/FAST/R/323F40~1.1/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l 
  "C:\FAST\R\3.2.1\library" C:\Users\R612965
\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpMRjXXu/downloaded_packages/Boom_0.5.tar.gz' had status 1
Warning in install.packages :
installation of package ‘Boom’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
‘C:\Users\R612965\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpMRjXXu\downloaded_packages’
```

I have also tried install dependencies 'BoomSpikeSlab' and 'Boom' first which returns me very similar issue like the one above - 'had status 127'. Directly install from source file like tar.gz is also not working. How can I approach this issue?

I have also attached my session information below:

```
R version 3.2.1 (2015-06-18)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] BH_1.60.0-2      sqldf_0.4-10     RSQLite_1.0.0    DBI_0.5-1       gsubfn_0.6-6     proto_1.0.0      dtplyr_0.0.1     data.table_1.9.6 reshape2_1.4.2  
[10] scales_0.4.1     gtable_0.2.0     dplyr_0.5.0      devtools_1.12.0  httr_1.2.1      

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] Rcpp_0.12.7      magrittr_1.5     munsell_0.4.3    colorspace_1.2-7 R6_2.2.0         stringr_1.1.0    plyr_1.8.4       tcltk_3.2.1      tools_3.2.1     
[10] grid_3.2.1       git2r_0.15.0     withr_1.0.2      assertthat_0.1   digest_0.6.10    tibble_1.2       curl_2.2         memoise_1.0.0    stringi_1.1.2   
[19] chron_2.3-47
```

I am using Windows 7 op.

Comment: I don't see any mention of your having installed Rtools, so that would be my first recommendation.